# Not being able to select the same name into a form

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

So I have this form where i can fill in companies but right now I am being able to insert multiple companies with the same name but I don't want that.. I want the name of the company to be unique or else if I put in the same name thats already in the database it should give me an error.

How can I do that?

This is my form in my view html:

```
  <br>
        <center> <h3> Instituut toevoegen </h3>  </center>
        <br>
                <?php  echo form_open('index.php/Instituut/Add_instituut'); ?>

                     <div class="form-group">
                     <label>Instituut:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="instituut" id="instituut"  type="text">
                </div>

                         <div class="form-group">
                             <label>Telefoonnummer van instituut:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="instituuttelefoon" id="instituuttelefoon"  type="text">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="Add_instituut" >Toevoegen</button>
                </div>
            </form>       
        </div>
```

This is the controller function:

```
public function Add_instituut()
        {
            if (isset($_POST['Add_instituut'])) {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('instituut', 'Instituut', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('instituuttelefoon', 'instituuttelefoon', 'required');

            //If form validation true
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

                //voeg werknemer toe in database
                $data = array (
                    'instituut'=>$_POST['instituut'],
                    'instituuttelefoon'=>$_POST['instituuttelefoon'],
                    );
                $this->db->insert('instituut',$data);

                $this->session->set_flashdata("success", "u heeft een nieuw instituut toegevoegd");
                redirect("index.php/Instituut", "refresh");
            }
        }
    }
```

I probably should add something in the form validation rules?

instituut means company name
Thanks
any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: I don't see an opening `<form>` tag. All I see is a closing `</form>` one. So, the method is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `is_unique` in form validation rules

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('instituut', 'Instituut', 'required|is_unique[your_table_name.instituut]');
```

check tutorial. for unique value:

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference

Comment: My table name is instituut so I have to do it like this: @b.desai $this->form_validation->set_rules('instituut', 'Instituut', 'required|is_unique[instituut]');

Comment: And what is field name?

Comment: Ah also instituut so I have to do instituut.instituut?

Comment: When I fill in a form with a unique name nothing is getting uploaded into my database anymore since I added that vorm validation rule?

Comment: I have it like this is it correct? : $this->form_validation->set_rules('instituut', 'Instituut', 'required|is_unique[instituut.instituut]'); the form doesnt upload when I submit the form anymore